# How to setup path for NDK in intellIDEA community edition?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-ndk

I created an android project with C++ support by having error in Gradle syn process. I' m having error as following

> Gradle syn failed: NDK not configured
>
> Download it with sdk manager
>
> Consult IDE log for more

I already have ndk in my system but dont know how i set NDK path for android project in intellIDEA.

Comment: Why not just download android studio, which is a version of intellij with all the Android stuff already set up?  You're asking for a lot of pain in redoing all that.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition has no support for C++ or NDK. Please use Android Studio.